# Data fails to load due to permissions but only initially

Tags: firebase

What's happening is that usually the first time I authenticate a user after enough time has passed that the session has expired my requests for data that the user should have access to are denied.  The requests will start working eventually with no actual rules or code changing.  It can take from 2 to 10 minutes but will eventually right itself.

I don't have hard data on this; it's just something I've observed.

I have no idea what I can do about this.  Is anyone else seeing this?  Is this a known bug?  I've search but haven't found any other accounts of this happening.

Thanks.

here are the rules:

```
{
 "rules": {

    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read" :"$user == auth.id || data.child('email').val() == auth.email",
        ".write":"$user == auth.id"
      }
    },

    "todos":{
      "$list":{
        ".read":"data.child('members').hasChild(auth.id)",
        ".write":"newData.child('members').hasChild(auth.id)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried calling unauth() and then auth() again?

Comment: Could you post your security rules, and any other info that might help us reproduce the issue? Also, how long does it take for the session to "expire" the first time?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I have a callback set up from the FirebaseAuthClient that informs the app if the user is logged in.  If the state is logged out then authClient.login is called (with the credentials).  This succeeds and I get back the confirmation.  A reload at this point will also show that the user is still authenticated.

Comment: session timeout was set a the default (24hrs?) but I've now reduced it to its min value of 1hr.  I've added the rules used in the post.  but keep in mind that the rules do work.  they just don't work for a few minutes after the initial login.

Comment: (assuming the answer below doesn't help) Can you provide a repro? If you need to share confidential info to do that, please email me andrew at firebase dot com.

Comment: I'm actually seeing the same behavior... After (successfully) logging in after a long period of not logging in, I get "permission denied" on everything for a couple minutes. Then it just goes away.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your auth tokens live for 24 hours, so if you're seeing security errors before then, it's probably not related to your session. To verify this, you can attach a callback to tell you when your session has expired. See:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/auth.html

I suspect what's going on here is simply that the data your rules are depending on is changing and causing writes to succeed some times, and fail others. This is the intended behavior of Security Rules in Firebase. For example, if someone was added / removed from /todos/blah/members/ it would affect your ability to read at /todos/blah

One odd thing about your rules is that you appear to be allowing anyone to write to /todos/$list as long as the data they are writing contains a member list that contains the writer's user id. I suspect this is not your intended behavior. Perhaps you meant to make the write rules depend on the data that was already in Firebase rather than new data?